# Mezzanine FileBrowser not allowing me to select an image

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, mezzanine

I am using mezzanine to deploy a simple blog website. Each part of the website has a header that needs to be easily changed by the blog team. My solution was to make a model with a `FileField` for the blog team to change a pages header on the admin page. I am using S3 bucket to store static and media files.

**Chief Complaint:** When a user goes to upload a photo, the file gets uploaded to the S3 bucket, but I can't click the select button on the file that I am looking to use. [Mezzanine file selector button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYrKP.png).

**My implementation:**

I mainly used [this tutorial](http://www.leehodgkinson.com/blog/my-mezzanine-s3-setup/) to implement the backend for the file uploader (I only used S3).

*settings.py*

```
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
STATICFILES_LOCATION = 'static'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'custom_storages.StaticStorage'
STATIC_URL = "https://%s/%s/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, 
STATICFILES_LOCATION)

MEDIAFILES_LOCATION = 'media'
MEDIA_URL = "https://%s/%s/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, 
MEDIAFILES_LOCATION)
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'custom_storages.MediaStorage'
MEDIA_ROOT = ''
```

*custom_storages.py*

```
from django.conf import settings
from storages.backends.s3boto import S3BotoStorage
from filebrowser_safe.storage import S3BotoStorageMixin

class StaticStorage(S3BotoStorage, S3BotoStorageMixin):
    location = settings.STATICFILES_LOCATION


class MediaStorage(S3BotoStorage, S3BotoStorageMixin):
    location = settings.MEDIAFILES_LOCATION
```

*models.py*

```
class Header(models.Model):
    file = FileField("File", max_length=200, format="Image",
        upload_to=upload_to("galleries.GalleryImage.file", ""))

    # other fields ...
```

**Error messages:**

```
 FB_FileBrowseField.js:16 Uncaught TypeError: 
     Cannot set property 'value' of null at FileSubmit (FB_FileBrowseField.js:16) 
     at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (?pop=1&type=Image:230)
```

*FB_FileBrowserField.js*

```
function FileSubmit(FilePath, FileURL, ThumbURL, FileType) {
    var input_id=window.name.replace(/____/g,'-').split("___").join(".");

    // left out variables for post simplicity

    input = opener.document.getElementById(input_id);

    // set new value for input field
    input.value = FilePath;

    // cut out rest of the code
```

The problem seems to be that the opener method returns `null`. I assume this is because it can't find the input_id in the html. I can't seem to figure out why this is an error, since I am using the out of the box software. I'm wondering if anyone could point me in the right direct for better diagnosing this problem and potentially fixing it.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably uploading a file with an extension that Mezzanine does not recognize as an image.

The default extensions are set in [filebrowser-safe](https://github.com/stephenmcd/filebrowser-safe/blob/master/filebrowser_safe/settings.py):

```
'Image': ['.jpg', '.jpeg', '.gif', '.png', '.tif', '.tiff', '.svg']
```

You can modify or create your own extensions with the `FILEBROWSER_EXTENSIONS` setting, e.g.:

```
FILEBROWSER_EXTENSIONS = {
    'Image': ['.jpg', '.jpeg', '.gif', '.png', '.tif', '.tiff', '.svg', '.image'],
}
```

Alternately, you can modify or create your own format with `FILEBROWSER_SELECT_FORMATS`, which takes a dictionary of names (to pass to `FileField`'s `format` parameter) and lists of extensions (must be defined in the default `EXTENSIONS` or `FILEBROWSER_EXTENSIONS`). For example :

```
FILEBROWSER_SELECT_FORMATS = {
    'Multimedia': ['Image', 'Video', 'Audio'],
}
```